# Problems with passing two models to one view

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i want to pass two models to one view  using  a ViewModel

My models :

```
     public class Candidat
     {
     public int Id { set; get; }
     public string num_cin    { set; get; }
     public ICollection<Poste> postes { get; set; }
     }

     public class Poste
     {
     public int Id { set; get; }
     public string poste_name {set;get}
     public List<Candidat> candidats {set;get;}
      }

    public class PosteCandidatViewModel
      {

    public Candidat candidat { get; set; }
    public Poste poste { get; set; }
       }
```

the  controller  action :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index( Poste poste,string num_cin)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var v = (from c in _db.Candidats
                     where c.num_cin == num_cin
                     && c.postes.Any(p => p.Id == poste.Id)
                     select c)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

            if (v != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Inscription", "Candidat");
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "BureauOrdre");
            }

            }
        return View();
```

the  view :

```
        @model ProcRec.Models.PosteCandidatViewModel

        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.candidat.num_cin)</td>

         <td><p>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.poste.Id,new 
           SelectList(ViewBag.Postes, "Id", "intitule_poste"),"choisir le poste")
          </p></td>
```

my  problem  is  that   the  linq  query  is  not  giving  the result  i  want 
(but  if  i  gave  to  num_cin  an  poste.id  some  values   it's  work )

so  the  problem  is  that    num_cin   not have a  valu  from  dropdownlist  ...it's  like  having an empty value!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the POST method signature to accept the model, and the access the model properties

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PosteCandidatViewModel model)
{
  Poste poste  = model.Poste;
  string num_cin = model.Candidat.num_cin;
```

The reason that parameter `string num_cin` is null is because `@TextBoxFor(model => model.candidat.num_cin)` generates `<input type="text" name="candidat.num_cin" ... />`which is trying to map to property `candidat` that contains property `num_cin`. Alternatively upi can use

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index( Poste poste, [Bind(Prefix="candidat")]string num_cin)
{
```

Note, if `ModelState` is invalid, you need to reassign the the value of `ViewBag.Postes` that you use in `DropDownListFor()`

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  ....
}
ViewBag.Postes = // set the value here before returning the view
return View(model);
```

Comment: i  tried that it gives me an exception .................Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items (DrodownList)

Comment: Where is the exception occurring?

Comment: i fixed the exception it's  because of a validation  that  i have in my models.......i dont want to pass  PosteCandidatViewModel  as a parametre of my Post action....because if i did that  it  gives  me  some  validation errors (because my models cauntans a lot of required attributes  )

Comment: Where is your form in your `.cshtml` view file?

Comment: seems like is not workin  !! :(  num_cin still have  null   !!!!!!! i hate this kind of problems

Comment: @saidmohamed11, Not sure why its not working for you - I've used `Bind Prefix` before but not with multiple parameters or with primitive types so that may be the problem. If `Candidat` contains other required properties that prevent validation, you really should be using a view model that contains only the properties you want to post back. For example `PosteCandidatViewModel` has `public Poste poste { get; set; }` and `public string num_cin { get; set; }`

Comment: think you for your help i will make the question as answered